# What is the proper way to encapsulate this kind of functionality?

Tags: encapsulation

For example I have a function that basically works this way:

```
function myfunc(data,type_of_analysis){
    if type_of_analysis is "Smith-Jones Method" 
          return smith_jones(data)
    else if type_of_analysis is "Pineapple-Mango Method"
          return pineapple_mango(data)
}
```

Names are made up of course, and imagine that there are several more types of analysis than this. What would be the correct way to restructure myfunc()? Is there a better / more standard way for people to pass in arguments to determine what kind of analysis they want to perform? Or is this something the user would have to look up in a documentation?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the Strategy pattern.

Comment: I did see Strategy Pattern but did not quite understand how to apply it in my case.

Comment: Are you talking something like if `myfunc(5, int)` the it should return 5 of type `int` and `myfunc(5, str)` should return `"5"` of data type `str` ?

Comment: You'd implement each type of analysis in a class, and then instantiate the correct implementation based on your `type_of_analysis`. Of course, you'd still have to `if / elseif` or `switch` (or function pointers) to determine what strategy to apply. Strategy pattern is good if your actual analysis is complex enough to warrant being in a class.

Comment: My question is rather if I should be handling "type_of_analysis" differently. Is it acceptable to request a user to submit arguments like "smith-jones" or is that bad practice?

Comment: You might be better translating that string into an enum for better safety.

Comment: Obviously it is not a good practice, There may be typos in the input by the user, However you can use regex in case of mixed upper and lower cases , like `this_formula` and `This_formula` should point to same thing.

Comment: Well, this depends of your case I suppose. Lets say that data is an array of integer. Analysis might be: find max, find min, calc average. I guess it can be acceptable to switch on the name of your analysys, but as @TartanLlama suggest, using an enum would be safer / less error prone.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "use an enum." Like passing in 1, 2, 3, etc instead of a string? How would the user know which number meant what?

Comment: I mean having the user pass in a string, then internally turning it into an enum, throwing exceptions or similar if something goes wrong. For example, writing a function that turns "Smith-Jones Method", "Smith Jones Method", "smith jones method" etc. into `AnalysisMethod::SmithJones`.

Comment: I still don't understand how this is an "enum." I understand that the string should be parsed in some way so it knows which method/function to call.

Comment: I mean (in C++ for example), defining an enum like `enum class AnalysisMethod {SmithJones, PineappleMango};` then writing a function like `AnalysisMethod stringToMethod (std::string);`.

Comment: How does that make things any safer than just parsing the string and then calling the correct function in a giant switch/if statement?

Comment: Because it canonicalizes the input and gives you a single point of failure for input parsing.

Comment: So it just sort of modularizes it? Like "here's the accepted function names, here's the input, does it match any of these?"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in C++ which uses a map between enum values and function objects to give a type safe and flexible dispatch framework:

```
//dummy analysis functions
void smithJonesAnalysis (int data){cout << "Smith";}
void pineappleMangoAnalysis (int data){cout << "Pineapple";}

class Analyzer
{
    //different analysis methods
    enum class AnalysisMethod {SmithJones, PineappleMango};
    //a map from analysis method to a function object
    std::map<AnalysisMethod, std::function<void(int)>> m_analysis_map;

    AnalysisMethod stringToMethod (std::string method)
    {
        //some basic string canonicalisation
        std::transform(method.begin(), method.end(), method.begin(), ::tolower);
        if (method == "smith-jones method")
            return AnalysisMethod::SmithJones;
        if (method == "pineapple-mango method")
            return AnalysisMethod::PineappleMango;

        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid analysis method");
    }
public:
    Analyzer()
    {
        //register all the different functions here
        m_analysis_map[AnalysisMethod::SmithJones] = smithJonesAnalysis;
        m_analysis_map[AnalysisMethod::PineappleMango] = pineappleMangoAnalysis;
    }

    //dispatcher function
    void operator() (std::string method, int data)
    {
        AnalysisMethod am = stringToMethod(method);
        m_analysis_map[am](data);
    }
};
```

It is used like so:

```
Analyzer a;
a("Smith-Jones Method", 0);
a("Pineapple-Mango Method", 0);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/cMyr0N)

This has a bunch of advantages compared to simple switch statements:

- It's easier to add/remove analysis methods
- It's way easier to change the type of data which the methods accept
- You could have different `Analyzer`s for different areas, templated and specialized, and all you'd need to change would be the registration method.
- You could enable/disable analysis methods at runtime in a very clear fashion